# Printing in Linux using Python

Tags: python, linux, printing, pi

Good day,

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi project and one of the features is to print a .docx hard copy. Unfortunately, the `os.startfile(filename, "print")` method does not work on Linux. Is there a good workaround for this? I'm using Python 3.7 for this project.

Thank you.

Comment: use subprocess to do so

Comment: How would you print the document from the command line?